How to navigate to different destinations for responsive UIs with Jetpack Compose Navigation?
I'd like to display a full screen content for compact screens and show the same content as a dialog for larger screens sizes.
In addition to that I would like to have a ViewModel that is scoped to that specific destination so it can be cleared whenever user leaves that destination.
What is the recommended way of navigation to different screen representation with Jetpack Compose Navigation?
I tried to navigate to the dialog composable as described in the official doc: dialog composable, and depending on the screen size I show a full screen content or a dialog-style one.
Although, I can get an issue that the bottom navigation bar is grayed out, which can be easily handled by:
if (isCompactDevice) {
    // Remove possible scrim around dialog area, e.g. bottom navigation bars
    (LocalView.current.parent as DialogWindowProvider).window
        .setDimAmount(1f)
}

which is not that ideal.
Does any one know what would be the recommended way of such navigation?

Wouldn't you be able to make better use of the additional screen space on larger displays? Like with a ListDetailPaneScaffold?

Thanks a lot for the answer! Tbh, I'm not quite sure if ListDetailPaneScaffold fits there as this component is more likely designed for master-detail or list-detail flows. This component takes two arguments listPane and detailPane  for each. In my particular case it's more about full-screen/dialog style design

You can do one thing, use the ConstraintLayout to handle different screen sizes and manage the threshold of the screen size like dp or pixels as per your need. Create dialog layout code for larger screen size and full screen code for compact screen size using ConstraintLayout using conditional code.
Below is the sample code for the compose to handle different screen size to show the ui with responsiveness using ConstraintLayout you can change the code as per your need.
@Composable
fun MainScreen(viewModel:MainViewModel, navController: NavController) {
val screenSize = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
val isCompactScreen = screenSize < 600 // You can adjust this threshold as needed

val modifier = if (isCompactScreen) {
    Modifier.fillMaxSize()
} else {
    Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)
}

ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = modifier,
) {}


Unfortunately this doesn't work as when we navigate to a next screen with Compose Navigation it displays a separate blank screen with the content. Consequently I'm not able to display a dialog style content on larger screens over the previous back stack entry
